# Не запускается index.php на хостинге

Tags: php, html, хостинг, оптимизация-сайтов

Добрый день!
Создал сайт, залил на Hostinger.ru.

Зашёл на хостинг, полностью очистил корневую папку, после чего залил свой сайт.
В корне находится index.php, но сайт его не запускает и при загрузке моего сайта пишет:

> Index of /

Есть в корне сайта файл .htaccess в котором указал:

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .html .css
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) http://%1/$1 [L,R=permanent]
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

Но проблема остаётся. Как исправить её, что бы открывался index.php

Comment: Исправил ошибку. Если кому интересно: весь сайт нужно помещать в папку public_html, а не в корень хостинга.

Answer (score 3):

Если в показываемом списке нет вашего `index.php` (в смысле, "Index of /" — это всё, что вы видите), значит, вы залили свой `index.php` не в то место.

Comment: Спасибо, всё получилось. Сразу не сообразил куда весь сайт заливать нужно